# "Go to Definition" and "Peek Definition" functionalities are not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I try to see the definition of a Stored Procedure.
So I selected the object and click the "`Go to Definition`" / `F12` button. Even I tried "Peek definition" also.

But I am getting "No definition found for the Stored Procedure"

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here.
Any solution for this to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Go to Definition" comes from [LSP (Language Server Protocol)](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/)

An extension like [MySQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.vscode-mysql)) would not bring that feature.

Only an [LSP implementation](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers/) like:

- [lighttiger2505/sqls](https://github.com/lighttiger2505/sqls)
- [`Microsoft/vscode-mssql/src/languageservice`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/tree/dev/src/languageservice), part of the [SQL Server extension for Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15), would help.

Comment: Can you please provide any link/anything that can explain the steps to implement this, if you have. Thank you

Comment: @SASI First, check if the SQL server extension from Microsoft would help in your case (ie: this could already be implemented)

Comment: @SASI Second, to implement a new LSP instance in Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide

Comment: ok Thank you. I will check